# How can I simplify my code?

Tags: java, algorithm, simplify

I recently wrote a program that calculates the number of friday the thirteenth's after 1900. The code is perfectly fine and it works; however there are parts that are extremely redundant. Is there anyway I could simplify it.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class friday {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("friday.in"));
        PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("friday.out"));
        int years = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int saturday = 0;
        int sunday = 0;
        int monday = 0;
        int tuesday = 0;
        int wedensday = 0;
        int thursday = 0;
        int friday = 0;
        int month = 1;
        int day = 1;
        int months = 12*years;
        int test = 0;
        int year = 1900;

        for(int i = 0; i < months; i++)
        {
            if ((year % 4 == 0) && year % 100 != 0)
            {
                test = 1;
            }
            else if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 == 0))
            {
                test = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                test = 0;
            }

        if(month == 1)
        {
            if(day == 1)
            {
                saturday++;
            }
            if(day == 2)
            {
                sunday++;
            }
            if(day == 3)
            {
                monday++;
            }
            if(day == 4)
            {
                tuesday++;
            }
            if(day == 5)
            {
                wedensday++;
            }
            if(day == 6)
            {
                thursday++;
            }
            if(day == 0)
            {
                friday++;
            }
            day = (day + 3) % 7;
        }
        if(month == 2)
        {
            if(test == 1)
            {
                if(day == 1)
                {
                    saturday++;
                }
                if(day == 2)
                {
                    sunday++;
                }
                if(day == 3)
                {
                    monday++;
                }
                if(day == 4)
                {
                    tuesday++;
                }
                if(day == 5)
                {
                    wedensday++;
                }
                if(day == 6)
                {
                    thursday++;
                }
                if(day == 0)
                {
                    friday++;
                }
                //leapyear = 1;
                day = (day + 1) % 7;
            }
            else
            {
                if(day == 1)
                {
                    saturday++;
                }
                if(day == 2)
                {
                    sunday++;
                }
                if(day == 3)
                {
                    monday++;
                }
                if(day == 4)
                {
                    tuesday++;
                }
                if(day == 5)
                {
                    wedensday++;
                }
                if(day == 6)
                {
                    thursday++;
                }
                if(day == 0)
                {
                    friday++;
                }
                day = (day + 0) % 7;
                //leapyear++;
            }
        }
        if(month == 3)
        {
            if(day == 1)
            {
                saturday++;
            }
            if(day == 2)
            {
                sunday++;
            }
            if(day == 3)
            {
                monday++;
            }
            if(day == 4)
            {
                tuesday++;
            }
            if(day == 5)
            {
                wedensday++;
            }
            if(day == 6)
            {
                thursday++;
            }
            if(day == 0)
            {
                friday++;
            }
            day = (day + 3) % 7;
        }
        if(month == 4)
        {
            if(day == 1)
            {
                saturday++;
            }
            if(day == 2)
            {
                sunday++;
            }
            if(day == 3)
            {
                monday++;
            }
            if(day == 4)
            {
                tuesday++;
            }
            if(day == 5)
            {
                wedensday++;
            }
            if(day == 6)
            {
                thursday++;
            }
            if(day == 0)
            {
                friday++;
            }
            day = (day + 2) % 7;
        }
        if(month == 5)
        {
            if(day == 1)
            {
                saturday++;
            }
            if(day == 2)
            {
                sunday++;
            }
            if(day == 3)
            {
                monday++;
            }
            if(day == 4)
            {
                tuesday++;
            }
            if(day == 5)
            {
                wedensday++;
            }
            if(day == 6)
            {
                thursday++;
            }
            if(day == 0)
            {
                friday++;
            }
            day = (day + 3) % 7;
        }
        if(month == 6)
        {
            if(day == 1)
            {
                saturday++;
            }
            if(day == 2)
            {
                sunday++;
            }
            if(day == 3)
            {
                monday++;
            }
            if(day == 4)
            {
                tuesday++;
            }
            if(day == 5)
            {
                wedensday++;
            }
            if(day == 6)
            {
                thursday++;
            }
            if(day == 0)
            {
                friday++;
            }
            day = (day + 2) % 7;
        }
        if(month == 7)
        {
            if(day == 1)
            {
                saturday++;
            }
            if(day == 2)
            {
                sunday++;
            }
            if(day == 3)
            {
                monday++;
            }
            if(day == 4)
            {
                tuesday++;
            }
            if(day == 5)
            {
                wedensday++;
            }
            if(day == 6)
            {
                thursday++;
            }
            if(day == 0)
            {
                friday++;
            }
            day = (day + 3) % 7;
        }
        if(month == 8)
        {
            if(day == 1)
            {
                saturday++;
            }
            if(day == 2)
            {
                sunday++;
            }
            if(day == 3)
            {
                monday++;
            }
            if(day == 4)
            {
                tuesday++;
            }
            if(day == 5)
            {
                wedensday++;
            }
            if(day == 6)
            {
                thursday++;
            }
            if(day == 0)
            {
                friday++;
            }
            day = (day + 3) % 7;
        }
        if(month == 9)
        {
            if(day == 1)
            {
                saturday++;
            }
            if(day == 2)
            {
                sunday++;
            }
            if(day == 3)
            {
                monday++;
            }
            if(day == 4)
            {
                tuesday++;
            }
            if(day == 5)
            {
                wedensday++;
            }
            if(day == 6)
            {
                thursday++;
            }
            if(day == 0)
            {
                friday++;
            }
            day = (day + 2) % 7;
        }
        if(month == 10)
        {
            if(day == 1)
            {
                saturday++;
            }
            if(day == 2)
            {
                sunday++;
            }
            if(day == 3)
            {
                monday++;
            }
            if(day == 4)
            {
                tuesday++;
            }
            if(day == 5)
            {
                wedensday++;
            }
            if(day == 6)
            {
                thursday++;
            }
            if(day == 0)
            {
                friday++;
            }
            day = (day + 3) % 7;
        }
        if(month == 11)
        {
            if(day == 1)
            {
                saturday++;
            }
            if(day == 2)
            {
                sunday++;
            }
            if(day == 3)
            {
                monday++;
            }
            if(day == 4)
            {
                tuesday++;
            }
            if(day == 5)
            {
                wedensday++;
            }
            if(day == 6)
            {
                thursday++;
            }
            if(day == 0)
            {
                friday++;
            }
            day = (day + 2) % 7;
        }
        if(month == 0)
        {
            if(day == 1)
            {
                saturday++;
            }
            if(day == 2)
            {
                sunday++;
            }
            if(day == 3)
            {
                monday++;
            }
            if(day == 4)
            {
                tuesday++;
            }
            if(day == 5)
            {
                wedensday++;
            }
            if(day == 6)
            {
                thursday++;
            }
            if(day == 0)
            {
                friday++;
            }
            day = (day + 3) % 7;
            year++;
        }

        month = (month + 1) % 12;


    }
        pw.println(saturday + " " + sunday + " " + monday + " " + tuesday + " " + wedensday+ " " + thursday + " " + friday);
        pw.close();
        //System.out.println(saturday + " " + sunday + " " + monday + " " + tuesday + " " + wedensday+ " " + thursday + " " + friday);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have functional code, http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com is a more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: Do you know arrays ? Something tells me it could be useful. Or enums

Comment: **Comment from Parttimereaper :** 
Well I would probably use switch statements for readability or use the localdate object and just keep rolling it up by each month after setting it to the 13th and then checking if its a friday or not

Comment: `day = (day + 3) % 7` what is the logic of those statements ? I need to understand it to refactor them. How do you get the increment ?

Comment: It's disappointoing you don't help people to help you

Comment: This is from the logic of how in 31 days, the next 13th is 3 days after. So by using a modulo, it will reset within a day between monday-sunday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to improve your code greatly is to use arrays. Also, you must understand the logic of your `if` statements to be able to compress them. For readability, don't use `7` when you want to say `days in a week`, don't say `12` when you want to say `years in a month`. **Create constants with clear names and use them everywhere you need them.**

Below is the beginning of your first step of refactoring. Check this simplified code still works, and use it to improve it even more (better names, more explicit logic for `incrementForMonth`...).

```
public class friday {
    private static final int DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7;
    private static final int MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;

    private static void updateDays(int[] days, int day) {
        checkIsInRange(0, year, DAYS_IN_WEEK);
        days[(day + 4) % DAYS_IN_WEEK]++;
    }

    private static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
       checkIsInRange(0, year, MONTHS_IN_YEAR);
       return (year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
    }

    private static void checkIsInRange(int inclusiveLowerBound, int toTest, int exclusiveUpperBound) {
         if (toTest < inclusiveLowerBound || exclusiveUpperBound <= toTest) throw new IllegalArgumentException(toTest + " not in [" + inclusiveLowerBound + ", " + exclusiveUpperBound + "]");                 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("friday.in"));
        PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("friday.out"));
        int years = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        int month = 1;
        int day = 1;
        int months = MONTHS_IN_YEAR*years;
        int test = 0;
        int year = 1900;

        int days = int[DAYS_IN_WEEK];
        int[] incrementForMonth = { 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2 }; 

        for(int i = 0; i < months; i++) {
            test = isLeapYear(year) ? 1 : 0;

            updateDays(days, day);
            if (month != 2 || test == 1) {
                day = (day + incrementForMonth[month]) % DAYS_IN_WEEK;
            }
            if (month == 0) {
                year++;
            }
        }

        month = (month + 1) % MONTHS_IN_YEAR;
    }
    pw.println(saturday + " " + sunday + " " + monday + " " + tuesday + " " + wedensday+ " " + thursday + " " + friday);
    pw.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, your code doesn't do what your stated goal is. Anyway, the short answer is to use a `Calendar` object.

If you only want to count the number of Friday the 13th as you stated, here is the code:

```
public static int countFriday13(int years) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.clear();
    cal.set(1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 13);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < years * 12; i++) {
        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY)
            count++;
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I think the point of this kind of code is to do things by yourselves, not using powerful classes you did not write. There are many many good practices he need to learn, this is more important than using library code

Comment: @Dici there's nothing in the question to say he shouldn't use Calendar.  The code is terribly written; Calendar is exactly what he should be learning.  Research and orchestrate.

Comment: @duffymo the code is terribly written, so he should learn how to use arrays and methods, not high-level objects. What a weird logic you guys have. In his next program, he probably won't have a magic-library-class-doing-exactly-what-he-wants and he will not know how to write a fine code **on its own**. Writing code with libraries may be easier, but it is reserved to experienced programmers

Comment: I disagree. Calendar is not advanced. Your point about writing DRY code is correct.

Comment: It's not advanced, it's high-level.

Comment: @Dici @duffymo It all depends on the constraint of the task he was given, and since it's not stated, we can only guess. Reading the question again, I do however tend to agree with Dici, since it's tagged `algorithm`. I will however let my answer stand, since it does let him know there are alternatives, even if they fall outside his current constraints.